# Как правильно обработать события наведения и клика на Yandex Map?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Столкнулся с проблемой:

```
placemark1.events.add('mouseenter', function (e) {
          e.get('target').options.set('iconImageHref', 
'img/location_blue_on.svg');
        })
        .add('mouseleave', function (e) {
            e.get('target').options.unset('iconImageHref');
        })
        .add('click', function (e) {
          e.get('target').options.set('iconImageHref', 
'img/location_blue_on.svg');
        });
```

Из кода видно, что обрабатываю сперва наведение со сменой иконки, потом увод мыши с возвращением иконки. После чего обрабатывается клик, который так же меняет иконку. Затем (логично) при уводе мыши срабатывает событие `mouseleave`, которое здесь и мешает.
Можно ли что-то придумать?

Так же, при нажатии на другой маркер, иконка уже нажатого должна приходить в изначальное положение, и так по кругу со всеми маркерами.

Comment: Не ясна суть задачи. Какое поведение ожидалось? После клика иконка не должна меняться? Нужно просто флаг завести тогда.

Comment: после клика иконка должна меняться. но когда кликнули и увели мышь - не должна.

Comment: @MaxDenaro А если нажали на уже выбранный еще один раз? Должен он переключиться? (то есть при этом все станут как-бы не нажатыми)

Comment: Если нажали еще раз - остается как есть, не сбрасывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути вы пытаетесь сделать чекбокс. Для этого вам нужно где-то хранить состояние маркера. Один из вариантов - сделать свое свойство в `options` (назовем его `checked`). Если это свойство == true - не убираем `iconImageHref` при уходе курсора.

```
placemark1.events.add('mouseenter', function (e) {
    e.get('target').options.set('iconImageHref', 
'img/location_blue_on.svg');
})
.add('mouseleave', function (e) {
    var checked = e.get('target').options.get('checked');
    if (!checked) {
        e.get('target').options.unset('iconImageHref');
    }
})
.add('click', function (e) {
    var checked = e.get('target').options.get('checked');
    e.get('target').options.set('checked', !checked);
});
```

**Дополнено**
С учетом новых требований это уже будет радиокнопка. И тут нужно хранить состояние для группы объектов (только нужно будет еще решать вопрос принадлежности группе или вообще хранить состояние глобально). Логика несколько поменяется.

```
var selectedPlacemark;
placemark1.events.add('mouseenter', function (e) {
    e.get('target').options.set('iconImageHref', 
'img/location_blue_on.svg');
})
.add('mouseleave', function (e) {
    if (e.get('target') !== selectedPlacemark) {
        // убираем иконку только если это не текущий маркер
        e.get('target').options.unset('iconImageHref');
    }
})
.add('click', function (e) {
    if (e.get('target') !== selectedPlacemark) {
        if (!!selectedPlacemark) {
            // убираем иконку только если есть текущий маркер
            selectedPlacemark.options.unset('iconImageHref');
        }
        // сохраняем в переменной текущий маркер
        selectedPlacemark = e.get('target');
    }
});
```

Comment: Да, это сработало, но еще остался один момент. Теперь клик отрабатывается и иконка не меняется, но если кликнуть на любой другой маркер - клик не сбрасывается с уже нажатого. как быть?

Comment: @MaxDenaro для начала - поменять вопрос :) Такого там не было.

Comment: Можете помочь доделать? :)

Comment: @MaxDenaro дополните вопрос. Ответ не должен решать проблему, которой нет в вопросе

Comment: Да, уже дополнил.

Comment: А еще можно хранить информацию об активации непосредственно в самой метке. В state или в properties

Comment: @vsesh Согласен. Поэтому и написал: "Один из вариантов..." А вариантов очень много

Comment: Огромное спасибо, работает. Там еще одна логика при клике будет, но я думаю сам допру как-нибудь. Благодарю!